# Permanent Querystring on routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to figure out how to add a permanent querystring to all routes if a value is found in Vuex.

I'm doing this because if someone passes a specific querystring, it will lookup historical data for the entire site. So once they hit the app with the querystring, it adds it to vuex to fetch the data. After that, all routes should just append the querystring, just incase the user needs to link to historical data.

Currently, I've tried a few variations of this:

```
router.beforeResolve((to,from,next)=>{
 if(to.query.mystring == null || to.query.mystring == 'undefined'){
  router.push({ query: Object.assign({}, to.query, { mystring: 'newValue' }) });
 }
 next();
})
```

Before each route, I try to append it. This only seems to work the first time, otherwise i get this:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this.

```js
router.beforeResolve((to,from,next)=>{
 if(to.query.mystring == null || to.query.mystring == 'undefined'){
  next({ ...to, query: Object.assign({}, to.query, { mystring: 'newValue' }) })
 } else {
    next();
 }
})
```

Hope it help's